# Download speed limit script doesn't work

Tags: php

I've find a script [here](http://priteshgupta.com/2011/07/limit-file-download-speed-using-php/) which permit to limit the download speed of a file.

```
// The file that will be sent to the user
$your_file = 'file.zip';

// Rename the file name
$new_file = 'new-filename.zip';

// Set the download speed limit (70 kb/s)
$download_speed = 70;

if(file_exists($myl_file) && is_file($my_file)) {

    // Headers
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($my_file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$new_file);

    // Flush the content
    flush();

    // File stream
    $file = fopen($my_file, "r");

    while (!feof($file)) {

        // Send the current part of the file to the browser
        echo fread($file, round($download_speed* 1024));

        // Flush the content to the browser
        flush();

        // Sleep one second
        sleep(1);
    }

    // Close file stream
    fclose($file);

}
else {
    die('Error: The file '.$my_file.' does not exist!');
}
```

The problem is that the speed limit doesn't works (but I can download the file) I'm always between 1500-2000 kb/s when I change the $download_speed value. I've test it on wamp and on a webserver but impossible to make it work. Any ideas? Thanks you.

Comment: What size files are you using? What happens to the execution time?

Comment: I'm trying with a 20,0 MB file. I can download the file during execution time.